# SQL Server Stock age calculation - Alternative to nested cursors

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do some kind of stock age calculation based on two tables. 
I have a current stock for each reference and I'd like to match it with the most recent warehouse entrances until I have no units left.

My Stock_Table looks like this

```
| Product_Ref |  Stock  |
| ----------- | ------- |
|  Prod_A     |   100   |
|  Prod_B     |   50    |
```

My Entrances_Table (ordered by most recent date) looks like this

```
| Product_Ref |  Month  |  Units  |
| ----------- | ------- | ------- |
|  Prod_A     |  July   |    50   |
|  Prod_A     |  June   |    30   |
|  Prod_A     |  May    |    35   |
|  Prod_B     |  May    |    10   |
|  Prod_B     |  April  |    55   |
```

What I need (as a previous step to do some other calcuations that I have already figured out) is to build this results table:

```
| Product_Ref |  Month  |  Units  |
| ----------- | ------- | ------- |
|  Prod_A     |  July   |    50   |
|  Prod_A     |  June   |    30   |
|  Prod_A     |  May    |    20   | <-- previous 50+30 so only 20 "left" to achive 100 units
|  Prod_B     |  May    |    10   |
|  Prod_B     |  April  |    40   | <-- previous 10 so only 40 "left" to achive 100 units
```

I know I could iterate throught both tables with a nested cursor, but I would like to know if there's a more elegant solution (maybe via running sums, using lead() , CTE, or something that I'm missing  ... )

Any ideas are appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired output by using `Sum() over(order by)`. This function returns running total of the column in SQL. So the query will be:

```
SELECT  A.Product_Ref ,
        A.Month ,
        CASE WHEN A.RT <= A.Stock THEN A.Units ELSE A.Stock - (LAG(A.RT) OVER (ORDER BY A.id)) END AS Units
FROM    ( SELECT    Product_Ref, Units, Month, Stock, Id ,
                    SUM(E.Units) OVER ( PARTITION BY E.Product_Ref ORDER BY E.Id ) AS RT
          FROM      Entrances E
                    INNER JOIN Stock S ON S.Prod = E.Product_Ref
        ) A;
```

To view the output of the query click on **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4dadfcd27a485ce900b2716c83d2b98)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query,

You can use `Lead()` in `sql-server` for check next row value of particular column.

```
select et.Product_Ref, et.Month, et.Unit,
   case when  SUM(et.Unit) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Ref ORDER BY id) > st.Unit1 
   OR 
   (lead(et.id)over( order by et.id)) is null
   then  
       case when lead(et.Product_Ref) over(order by id) <> et.Product_Ref
       AND 
       (  et.unit - ((SUM(et.Unit) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Ref ORDER BY id) ) - st.Unit1) ) <= 0
       then   -- (-)ve Stock
         st.Unit1 - ((SUM(et.Unit) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Ref ORDER BY id) )) 
       else  -- Stock Adjustment As per Stock_Table 
       et.unit - ((SUM(et.Unit) OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Ref ORDER BY id) ) - st.Unit1)  
       end
   else et.unit -- Normal Stock
   end as outputvalue
from Entrances_Table et
left join Stock_Table st on st.Product_Ref1 = et.Product_Ref
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db6f219daa8f59aa48febd16c6ea8cc6)**

Comment: @A L, Many of the condition checked in this query, 1) if Product_Ref is not in sequence then to it will give correct ans. 2) No sub query so it will run faster 3) if you will have continues max values than your stock then to this query will give you correct answer